# Projection matrix: What do we do when columns of A is not independent (in other word, not full column rank)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projection

Thank you for reading my question.
I'm watching the Linear algebra open course by Prof.Gilbert Strang. (https://ocw.mit.edu/18-06SCF11). Today, I learned that the projection matrix is $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$.

**Here is the question:**
In my opinion, there must be a projection matrix if the projection exists.
**What would the projection matrix be if $(A^TA)$ is not invertible?**
Is that something about pseudo-inverse? If so, just a single yes is ok for me, I'll keep learning and try to figure out what it is.

Every answer is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse is useful here. I won't spoil how (unless you want me to!), since you seem keen to learn for yourself. Alternatively, you can just remove linearly dependent columns from $A$ until the columns are linearly independent (with the same span). Let this new matrix be $B$. Then, the projection matrix, onto the same subspace, would be $B(B^\top B)^{-1}B^\top$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you for your answer! It helps a lot.

Comment: @snowman To supplement the other comment a bit: once you can find the MP pseudoinverse $A^+$, you can compute the matrix of the projection onto the column space of $A$ via the formula $P = AA^+$. In the case that $A^TA$ is invertible (equivalently where $A$ has linearly independent columns), we have $A^+ = (A^TA)^{-1}A^T$, which leads to the formula that you have already seen.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks a lot! This helps me figure out the relation.